# C# format {0} {1} {2} {3} values from web.config

Tags: c#

Hey all I have this code:

```
tmpConnString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["devConn_HRDB"].ConnectionString, _tmpValuesBack[3], _tmpValuesBack[1], _tmpValuesBack[4], _tmpValuesBack[2]);
```

And its referencing this in the web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="devConn_HRDB" connectionString="Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};Initial Catalog={3};"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And the error I am getting with the **_tmpValuesBack[3], _tmpValuesBack[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhEZZ.png), _tmpValuesBack[4], _tmpValuesBack[2]** is:

> Method name expected

So I'm not really sure what its asking for there....**_tmpValuesBack** is defined as a **string[] _tmpValuesBack = getHRPW().Split('|');** array.
[image]

Comment: This should work.  Can you show more complete code and the exact error?  (perhaps as a screen shot?)

Comment: I like to divide up things sometimes when I'm stuck. Set a variable for the value from web.config separately? Debug and make sure that value and string array has values you expect?

Comment: are you using string.Format or String.Format??

Comment: @apomene [There's no difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string).

Comment: What's the type of the variable _tmpValuesBack? Is it just a simple array? I think the error is on this variable, where one of them may not have any value. Could you separate each value into a string variable so that you could see how it is failing?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Sometimes [there is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15543841/11683) ;)

Comment: defining _tmpValuesBack as `var _tmpValuesBack = new string[] {"zero","one","two","three","four"};` makes this work fine for me. something else is wrong, or you have a syntax error that you didn't copy into the post.

Comment: @GSerg Only when the implementation is buggy :)

Comment: can you post the whole file as code? And, I hate to say it, but did you try restarting VS?

Comment: wow.... @DrewJordan go ahead and make that the official answer as restarting VS corrected it....

Comment: that's not an answer.... I would just close your question. cheers!

Comment: @DrewJordan Sure its an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that should work fine, sometimes the compiler can get messed up. Try restarting VS and see if that helps.